# Get MAC Address in Xamarin Forms for Android 11 for intern Enterprise application on Zebra devices

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

We are currently in the stages of upgrading from Android 10 to Android 11 for our zebra devices, with this also comes some updates concerning the retrieving of MAC Address. We manage our devices with a custom API to store some extra information about our devices, but for deployments we use VmWare's AirWatch. Now the issue we are facing is that we need "a link" between the device entity in our own db and the device in AirWatch.

Previously we used the serialnumber for this and after that (Android 10) we used Mac Address with following implementation to get MAC:

```
 var ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                                    .OrderBy(intf => intf.NetworkInterfaceType)
                                    .FirstOrDefault(intf => intf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                                    && (intf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211));
                if (ni == null)
                    return "";
                var hw = ni.GetPhysicalAddress();

                mac = string.Join(":", (from ma in hw.GetAddressBytes() select ma.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
```

Because this is now also blocked in Android 11 I was wondering if there is still any way to get this parameter as we really need some type of hardware identifier that will be both available in our own db as in AirWatch.

Answer (score 0):

As your playing with Zebra, maybe you could get access to the device serial number thanks to its Zebra dedicated API. This article is all about it for Android 10+: https://developer.zebra.com/blog/access-serial-number-and-imei-mobile-computers-running-android-10-and-higher

and it comes with a GitHub sample: https://github.com/darryncampbell/OEMInfo-DeviceIdentifiers-Sample-Android

Don't forget the paskage visibility for Android 11+:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.zebra.zebracontentprovider" />
</queries>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).